# How to get non expiring access_token in Facebook?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I get my access token in page https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer and my app is able to post on a Facebook Page's wall.

However the `access_token` expires after an hour.

How can I get a non-expiring `access_token`?

Edit: Down voters: I've posted my own answer and if you read it you'll know that my solution is never found in the FB docs nor in SO.

Comment: @CBroe Yup. I saw a few questions here in SO but non actually has a clear answer.

Comment: @CBroe I think the links posted is not a solution for apps that need to post when the user is not actively using the app?

Comment: I think facebook change this, because the offline access was to dangerous to users itself. One app with this permission have the control of when and where to do what he can (depends on the other permissions that you geve to it.

So, if you have a web app, or desktop app, or mobile app, etc, you only can do thinks when user its online of was online in a sort time. Or perhaps if you wanna maintain that token alive, run a daemon that ask for new token every X time.

Answer (score 7):

To all those who down voted and voted for close, I want to let you know that there is no clear answer here on SO.

After so much pain trying to make sense of FB's confusing docs, the answer to this question is rather extremely simple:

1. Set your app to **Native/Desktop** so you can get a 60-day token (you'll turn this to permanent later). Do this by going to https://developers.facebook.com/apps/ Edit settings > Advanced > Choose Native/Desktop in the App type.
2. Go to https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/ select your app, and **Get Access Token**
3. In the **Extended Permissions** tab, select `manage_pages` and `publish_stream`
4. Now you have a 60-day temporary token.
5. To get your permanent token, go here and use your temporary token: `https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts?access_token=REPLACE_THIS_WITH_YOUR_TEMPORARY_TOKEN`

Behold, you will see **permanent access token** to all Facebook pages which you are an admin.

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH! i have been dealing with this problem for a while and have searched through millions of fb-documentation/SO pages, and this one helped finally, i got a 60 day temporary token.
Unfortenuately i can't get my permanent access token with your fifth tep. Have any ids? I get an empty data array

Comment: 2 years later, my [script](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13364131/953684) still works with this answer. NOW **THAT'S** PERMANENT TOKEN! THANK YOU SIR!

Answer (score 0):

You should use refreshing of Long-lived User Access Tokens.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/extending-tokens/

Comment: Well why use refreshing if you can have a permanent access token like my answer.