# ( Invalid Access Token used) When tryign to get test pages of facebook test_user

Tags: java, android, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get list of Facebook test_user pages, I created the test_user and gave it manage_pages permission and many other permissions just to be sure that the problem is not caused by invalid permissions and then I created a test_page using this user.

And when I paste the Access_token of the test_user in the graph explorer I can see my pages under user or page options list 
[this picture shows this situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IjRM1.png)

So, if I chose one of my pages I can do any query I want.
But, I need to get the list of user pages and when I try to do that I get an (Invalid access_token error).

**What I tried:**

- I followed this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13531596/how-to-get-non-expiring-access-token-in-facebook/13535102#13535102) and it did not help.
- I tried to increase *Data Access Expiration Time*
- I Created more than one test user and gave them all the possible permissions.

---

**My code :**

**Login code:**

```
// Granting read permissions
m_loginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("email", "pages_show_list"));
m_loginButton.registerCallback(m_callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Login successfully");
           // if login succeeded ask for publish permissions. 
            Collection<String> permissions = new ArrayList<String>();
            permissions.add("manage_pages");
            permissions.add("publish_actions");
              LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithPublishPermissions(LoginActivity.this,permissions);

            startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            Log.d(TAG, "Login canceled");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {

            Log.d(TAG, "Login failed with error :" + error.getMessage());
        }
    });
```

**Where I am trying to get user pages list :**

```
        GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
            new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                    try{
                        Log.d(TAG, "User Pages : " +  object.toString());
                    }
                    catch (Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            });
    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
    parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email,gender, birthday, ids_for_pages");
    request.setParameters(parameters);
    request.executeAsync();
```

Here when I add ids_for_pages field I get **Invalid access_token error message**