# Facebook server login auth issue.

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I'm trying to simply post to a facebook page as the page.

I created an app, set permissions ( manage_pages ), and requested an app token ( via https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/ ).

I think I'm almost there but I'm getting an "PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught OAuthException: (#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action" error.

```
<?php
require_once('facebook.php');
$config = array();
$config['appId'] = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$config['secret'] = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$config['fileUpload'] = false; // optional
$facebook = new facebook($config);

$access_token = "app token I got from link above";
$facebook->setAccessToken($access_token);

$page_id = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
$args = array(
        'access_token'  => $access_token,
        'message'       => "This is just a test.",
        'name' => "Just a test.",
        'link' => "http://www.xxxx.com/",
        'picture' => "http://www.xxxx.com/Logo.jpg",
        'actions' => array(
        'name' => 'See Pic',
        'link' => "http://www.xxxx.com/Logo.jpg"
        )

    );
   $post = $facebook->api("/$page_id/feed","post",$args);
```

Where am I missing to give auth so I can post to the page?  I've been over the settings under my app dashboard and don't see that I'm missing anything.

Thanks

Comment: Update:  I've read through just about all the docs. I've verified permissions and manage_pages, and publish_* are there.  I went to the fb page itself and made sure that the app has "Publish on your behalf" rights.  At this point I'm not sure why it thinks it has no permissions.

Comment: Update: As it turns out it works for posting to the user page. but NOT the "fan" page associated with it.

Comment: Fixed.  Went this route: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13364131/facebook-access-token-is-invalid-trying-to-post-to-facebook-website-page-via and the accepted answer there seemed to work.  I still have no idea why my app access_token would not work.