# How to make access token alive?

Tags: php, facebook, authorization

I get my *access token* from this [page](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) and my app is able signup through Facebook.

I want to keep the *access token* from the user alive forever. However the access_token expires after an hour.

How can I get a *non-expiring* `access_token`?

Comment: you can look at this post. at the last of the blog, he has described it how to do it: https://www.sammyk.me/access-token-handling-best-practices-in-facebook-php-sdk-v4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Facebook has several types of user tokens](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens) including User Access Tokens, App Access Tokens and Page Access Tokens.

User Access Tokens come in short-term and long-term variety. Short-term tokens last about 1-2 hours while long-term tokens last about 60 days. You can [upgrade short-term tokens to long-term tokens as documented by Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#extending). To simulate non-expiring tokens, Facebook allows you to [refresh the long-term tokens](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#refreshtokens) which their SDKs do automatically. In this case, as long as the user as authorized your app, this can be fairly transparent to the user, and keep the user logged in.

App Access Tokens do not expire unless the application secret is refreshed through your app settings.

Page Access Tokens are used to manage Facebook pages and come in both short-term and long-term varieties. The version you receive is based on the User Access Token submitted to receive a Page Access Token. A non-expiring Page Access Token can be retrieved by requesting with a Long-Term User Access Token.

Comment: yet, there is a "hacky" way if you just want badly "non-expiring access_token". my script runs 2 years now with the same token. see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13364131/facebook-access-token-is-invalid-trying-to-post-to-facebook-website-page-via

Comment: Interesting. Can you use that technique for users generally or just for an app's developers? The OP seems to be asking about tokens for other users while that accepted solution seems to only work for the app's developers.

Comment: Exactly. I never got to test this case with the answer on that question i linked to! I'm **guessing** it won't work, and even if it works, i wouldn't rely on this for production code. If you have the time to test this on non-admin users ill be glad to know the results!

Comment: I don't really understand why you don't use an eternal page access token if you just want to post to a page that you own... Using a user access token is the wrong approach for that IMHO

Comment: Thank you very much for answer.  Can you elaborate your answer? I dint get it from that facebook documentation.  I am working in server side, i get access token from the app side, how to keep that alive? If possible explain with code!.